# Extract a list of classes and their methods from a solution with their summary

Tags: vb.net

For documentation purposes, I want to extract a hierarchy of the code. Classes then their methods. I also want to get the 'summary' of each. By that I mean the following

```
 ''' <summary>
''' Summary of the class
''' </summary>
Private Class newclass

End Class
```

is there a way to get this done? I know there is a function in VS - code metrics, the result of which shows part of this, but that only displays the classes and methods, not the summary.

Comment: You would use Reflection for all of it. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2019/october/csharp-accessing-xml-documentation-via-reflection) is how you get the documentation.

Comment: If you're looking to create documentation, have a look at [Sandcastle Help File Builder](https://ewsoftware.github.io/SHFB/html/8e3f8757-0ef3-4772-bb2f-5d7ae57e50da.htm). It utilizes the XML code comments and creates a helpfile from these.